# How to joined 2 tables and output fields from the adjacent table?

Tags: node.js, knex.js, objection.js

everybody, could you please tell me

I use the objection.js (ORM) library for knex.js

joined Users and Roles tables, everything is great.

I use it:

`const users = await User.query().eager().roles')`

I'm getting it:

`{"id":1, "email": "ann@mail.com", "password": "qwe", "role":1, "roles":{"id":1, "name": "admin"}}`

But how can I get a flat structure? :

`{"id":1, "email": "ann@mail.com", "password": "qwe", "role "admin"}`

Answer (score 1):

I would normally expect Objection to do this with a `HasOneRelation` relationship, so I'm going to assume that's what you have here:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "email": "ann@mail.com",
  "password": "qwe",
  "role": 1,
  "roles": {
    "id":1,
    "name": "admin"
  }
}
```

If your users can only have one role at a time, that should be fine. To get a flat structure, you can either post-process it in JavaScript:

```
return {
  ...user,
  role: roles.name
}
```

or create a [virtual attribute](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/static-properties.html#static-virtualattributes):

```
export default class User extends Model {
  static get virtualAttributes() {
    return ['roleName'];
  }

  roleName() {
    return this.roles.name;
  }
  // ...
}
```

This will not stop the `roles` object from being added, but it'll provide a first-level alias for the name in the JSON.